# qt app crash but is not reproduced easily,I have captured the dump stack and how to find out the source code by the stack

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, crash, mingw

1. Qt app crash but is not reproduced easily
2. I have captured the dump stack and how to find out the source code by the stack

compile tool: mingw

OS:           windows

I work with android(linux) always before, we can use addr2line to find out the crash source code.

So:

How can we find out the source code function or line when app was tested by the test engineer and it crash with dump stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the final,try my best,I find two ways to debug the crash app offline:

---

**First**, we can use the addr2line.exe, which is located at {mingw path}/bin. For example, if you get the crash log like that:

```
"E:\\qt\\untitled5.exe"
"Exception Addr:  00904B21 :Module: C:\\Qt\\Qt5.9.0\\5.9\\mingw53_32\\bin\\Qt5Widgetsd.dll"
"Exception Code:  C0000005 :Read Address:  00000000"
"Instruction:  8B 01 8B 40 34 C7 04 24 00 00 00 00 FF D0 83 EC"
"Registers: "
"EAX: 00904B1E  EBX: 185304C8  ECX: 00000000  EDX: 18500048"
"ESI: 1851DD60  EDI: 755E16DD  ESP: 0028FD20  EBP: 0028FD68"
"EIP: 00904B21  EFlags: 00010202"
"00904B21  :C:\\Qt\\Qt5.9.0\\5.9\\mingw53_32\\bin\\Qt5Widgetsd.dll"
"0040187C  :E:\\qt\\untitled5.exe"
"004017AB  :E:\\qt\\untitled5.exe"
"004016BC  :E:\\qt\\untitled5.exe"
"00403B45  :E:\\qt\\untitled5.exe"
```

and we use addr2line to find out the crash point

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.9.0\Tools\mingw530_32\bin>addr2line.exe -f -e e:\qt\untitled5.exe 0040187C 004017AB 004016BC 00403B45
_ZN4testC2Ev
E:\qt\untitled5/test.cpp:6
_ZN10MainWindowC2EP7QWidget
E:\qt\untitled5/mainwindow.cpp:12
_Z5qMainiPPc
E:\qt\untitled5/main.cpp:35
WinMain@16
c:\Users\qt\work\qt\qtbase\src\winmain/qtmain_win.cpp:104
```

---

**second** ,use ExcHndl, one part of Dr.mingw. It is a good tool I think. The github project link:
[enter link description here](https://github.com/jrfonseca/drmingw)

adn it also has an sample, you will not miss it. And it has an crash report like that:

```
Error occurred on Wednesday, September 6, 2017 at 14:25:57.

untitled5.exe caused an Access Violation at location 008F4B21 in module Qt5Widgetsd.dll Reading from location 00000000.

Registers:
eax=008f4b1e ebx=005ff278 ecx=00000000 edx=184b0048 esi=005fdf48 edi=755e16dd
eip=008f4b21 esp=0028fd20 ebp=0028fd68 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010202

AddrPC   Params
008F4B21 00000001 00000000 00000001  Qt5Widgetsd.dll!hide  [c:/Users/qt/work/qt/qtbase/src/widgets/kernel/qwidget.cpp @ 8037]
00401890 00000001 00000000 00050900  untitled5.exe! ??   [E:/qt/untitled5/test.cpp @ 6]
     4: test::test()
     5: {
>    6:     test3 *p = new test3;
     7: }
     8: 
004017BF 00000000 184CED38 00050900  untitled5.exe! ??   [E:/qt/untitled5/mainwindow.cpp @ 10]
     8: {
     9:     ui->setupUi(this);
>   10:     test *t = new test;
    11: }
    12: 
004016D2 00000001 184CED38 00673108  untitled5.exe!qMain  [E:/qt/untitled5/main.cpp @ 29]
    27: 
    28:     QApplication a(argc, argv);
>   29:     MainWindow w;
    30:     w.show();
    31:
```